# Integration with Spectral Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Now, suppose I have a compactly supported spectral measure $E$ defined on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. My question is this, suppose we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ non necessarily continuous, converging uniformly to $f$ continuous, is it true that $||\int f_{n}dE-\int fdE||\to 0$? I know the result holds in strong operator topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Write $E_h(\Delta)=\langle E(\Delta)h,h\rangle$. Then
$$
\left\langle
\left|\left(\int_{\mathbb C} (f_n(t)-f(t))\,dE(t)\right)h,h
\right\rangle\right|
=\left|\int_{\mathbb C}(f_n(t)-f(t))\,dE_h \right|
\leq\int_{\mathbb C}|f_n(t)-f(t)|\,dE_h\leq\|f_n-f\|_\infty.
$$
As you can do this for any $h$, 
$$
\left\|\int_{\mathbb C} (f_n(t)-f(t))\,dE(t)\right\|\leq\|f_n-f\|_\infty.
$$